# How to set multiple values in a Pandas dataframe at once?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large dataframe and a list of many locations I need to set to a certain value. Currently I'm iterating over the locations to set the values one by one:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#large dataframe
column_names = np.array(range(100))
np.random.shuffle(column_names)

row_names = np.array(range(100))
np.random.shuffle(row_names)

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=column_names, index=row_names)

#index values to be set
ix = np.random.randint(0, 100,1000)

#column values to be set
iy = np.random.randint(0, 100,1000)

#setting the specified locations to 1, one by one
for k in range(len(ix)):
    df.loc[ix[k], iy[k]]=1
```

This appears to be prohibitively slow. For the above example, on my machine, the last for loop takes 0.35 seconds. On the other hand, if I do

```
df.loc[ix, iy]=1
```

only takes 0.035 seconds so it is ten times faster. Unfortunately, it does not give the correct result, as it sets all combinations of elements of `ix` and `iy` to 1. I was wondering whether there is a similarly fast way to set values of many locations at once, avoiding the iteration over the locations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the underlying [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) array with [`.values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) and use the position indices after conversion:

```
cols = pd.Series(range(df.shape[1]), index=df.columns)
idx = pd.Series(range(df.shape[0]), index=df.index)

df.values[idx.reindex(ix), cols.reindex(iy)] = 1
```

Minimal example:

```
# input
df = pd.DataFrame(index=['a', 'b', 'c'],
                  columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])

ix = ['a', 'b', 'c']
iy = ['A', 'C', 'A']

# output
     A    B    C
a    1  NaN  NaN
b  NaN  NaN    1
c    1  NaN  NaN
```

---

##### previous answer

```
df.values[ix, iy] = 1
```

Minimal example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(5), columns=range(5))
ix = [1, 2, 4]
iy = [1, 3, 2]
df.values[ix, iy] = 1
```

Output:

```
     0    1    2    3    4
0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  NaN    1  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  NaN  NaN  NaN    1  NaN
3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
4  NaN  NaN    1  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: I need to access the dataframe by the proper column and index name. Here I just produced a minimal example but my columns and indexes are not so nicely ordered as here.

Comment: @Botond then just convert the names to their indices, please update the question and I'll show you.

Comment: mozway thank you, I just updated the question.

Comment: Note that the indices must exist (if not you'll have an error)

Comment: it appears that `reindex` breaks whenever multiple columns or indices with the same name are present in the dataframe: `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`. I guess we need a mapping between pairs of `(ix, iy)` and pairs of `(idx, cols)`

Comment: @Botond well, in cas of duplicated indices which one to use is always ambiguous. In this case you would need to de-duplicate or to drop the duplicates before reindexing.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a simple way to index the Pandas dataframe using a set of index column pairs, however Pandas multi-indexing with Series objects may reduce your execution time.

The code you provided had an execution time of

```
16.9 ms ± 497 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Here is the alternative solution using pd.MultiIndex. This approach creates a Series object with a Multiindex, then indexes and sets values based on a Multiindex, finally it converts the Series to Dataframe.

```
#large dataframe
column_names = np.array(range(100))
np.random.shuffle(column_names)

row_names = np.array(range(100))
np.random.shuffle(row_names)

#create multiindex series
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([row_names, column_names])
df = pd.Series(index=index)

#index values to be set
ix = np.random.randint(0, 100,1000)

#column values to be set
iy = np.random.randint(0, 100,1000)

#setting the specified locations to 1
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([ix, iy])
df.loc[idx] = 1

# Convert to 2d dataframe
df = df.unstack(level=-1, sort=False)
```

This results in an execution time of

```
1.98 ms ± 40.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```